# Double Hyphen/Dash in SQL-Injection. What are they used for?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm currently learning how SQL-Injections work. On many teaching-websites there are examples shown, such as

```
SELECT fieldlist
FROM table
WHERE field = 'x' AND email IS NULL; --';
```

In the field 'field' the content thats going to be checked comes from a textfield or something similar from a website. The user-input in this case is `x' AND email IS NULL; --` 
What is the use of `--` ??

I saw a few similar examples but no explanation. Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 19):

Ohh nevermind. The `--` is used to out-comment the rest of the query...

Comment: In particular it is to comment out the `'` (and remainder) found in the original SQL command text; such that the query remains valid - although this not strictly required. Eg. `WHERE field = 'x' AND email IS NULL or '' = '';` would also be valid

Comment: Does it really matter if i comment out the remaining query? Since both variations are valid, the one with the comment seems cleaner.